# ¿Como puedo hacer un PIVOT con columnas Dinamicas?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de de generar una consulta utilizando la función PIVOT de SQL - server 2008.
La consulta en sí no tiene inconvenientes, ya que los valores que arroja son los correctos. Para EMP3 el query arroja totalmente NULL o 0, esto es correcto, pero necesito generar un query dinamico que no muestre la columna cuya suma sea 0.

El query lo detallo debajo:

```
    SELECT 
    [Fecha], [Cantidad],
    ISNULL([EMP1],0) AS [EMP1],
    ISNULL([EMP2],0) AS [EMP2],
    ISNULL([EMP3],0) AS [EMP3],
    ISNULL([EMP4],0) AS [EMP4]
    FROM(   
        SELECT 
        CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),de.FECHA, 103) As [Fecha], 
        ci.COD_EMP,
        SUM(bs.IMPORTE) as [Importe],
        SUM (CASE WHEN bs.CANTIDAD <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Cantidad]
        FROM TABLA1 lc (NOLOCK)
        JOIN TABLA2 bs (NOLOCK) ON lc.ID1 = bs.ID1
        JOIN TABLA3 so (NOLOCK) ON bs.soc_id = so.soc_id
        JOIN TABLA4 ci (NOLOCK) ON ci.COD_EMP = '<<funcion que arroja            COD_EMP sobre lc.ID>>'
        JOIN TABLA5 de (NOLOCK) ON bs.ID2 = de.ID2
        JOIN TABLA6 co (NOLOCK) ON bs.ID3 = co.ID3
        JOIN TABLA7 cb (NOLOCK) ON co.CTA = cb.CTA
        JOIN TABLA8 su (NOLOCK) ON cb.SUC = su.SUC
        WHERE co.CO_ID = '11111'
        AND bs.ESTADO in (6,7)
        AND de.FECHA BETWEEN CONVERT (DATETIME,'2017-10-24') AND CONVERT         (DATETIME,'2017-10-27')
        AND '<<FUNCION>>' <> so.COD_EMP
        AND lc.SERV = bs.SERV
        GROUP BY FECHA , '<<FUNCION>>'),ci.COD_EMP
    ) nuevatabla
    PIVOT (SUM(IMPORTE) FOR COD_EMP in ([EMP1], [EMP2],[EMP3], [EMP4])) AS         pvt 
    ORDER BY 1
```

El resulta es el siguiente:

```
    Fecha   Cantidad    EMP1    EMP2    EMP3    EMP4
    24/10/2017  1       0.00    5.96    0.00    0.00
    24/10/2017  4       66.71   0.00    0.00    0.00
    24/10/2017  8       0.00    0.00    0.00    4.05
```

¿De que forma puedo escribir este query para evitar que me muestre las columnas que sean completamente 0?.
Como comentario extra, la columna EMP3 puede tener datos dependiendo de la fecha y cualquier otra columna no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, respondiendo a tu pregunta *"¿De que forma puedo escribir este query para evitar que me muestre las columnas que sean completamente 0?"*: No puedes, no hay ninguna forma de quitar columnas de una consulta de manera dinámica. Ahora bien, nada te impide escribir una consulta dinámica y ejecutarla mediante `sp_executsql`.

Para poder hacerlo los pasos serían:

1. Insertar tu consulta en una tabla temporal
2. Verificar que columnas tienen únicamente 0 y armar una consulta dinámica que elimine columnas
3. Ejecutar la consulta

El punto 1 es simple, no me voy a extender, o creas la tabla temporal y haces un `INSERT INTO` de tu consulta o haces un `SELECT INTO #Temp` de tu consulta. Vamos a asumir que ya tenemos la consulta en una tabla temporal, para que sea funcional el ejemplo, hacemos esto:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    Fecha       DATETIME,
    Cantidad    INT,
    EMP1        NUMERIC(15,2),
    EMP2        NUMERIC(15,2),
    EMP3        NUMERIC(15,2),
    EMP4        NUMERIC(15,2)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (Fecha,Cantidad,EMP1,EMP2,EMP3,EMP4)
VALUES  ('20171024',1,0.00,5.96,0.00,0.00),
        ('20171024',4,66.71,0.00,0.00,0.00),
        ('20171024',8,0.00,0.00,0.00,4.05)
```

Vamos a crear una sentencia SQL dinámica excluyendo las columnas que no queremos:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT Fecha,Cantidad,' 

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 
        CASE WHEN D.EMP1 = 1 AND V.EMP1 = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'EMP1,' END +
        CASE WHEN D.EMP2 = 1 AND V.EMP2 = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'EMP2,' END +
        CASE WHEN D.EMP3 = 1 AND V.EMP3 = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'EMP3,' END +
        CASE WHEN D.EMP4 = 1 AND V.EMP4 = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'EMP4,' END
      FROM ( SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT EMP1) AS 'EMP1',
                     COUNT(DISTINCT EMP2) AS 'EMP2',
                     COUNT(DISTINCT EMP3) AS 'EMP3',
                     COUNT(DISTINCT EMP4) AS 'EMP4'
                     FROM #Temp
            ) D
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT TOP 1 EMP1, EMP2, EMP3, EMP4
                          FROM #Temp
            ) V
SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL , LEN(@SQL ) -1 ) + ' FROM #Temp'
```

La lógica es sencilla, si la columna tiene un único valor, y el valor de la primer fila es 0 podemos asumir que la columna entera tiene unicamente 0. Si revisamos la sentencia `@SQL` vemos más claro lo que logramos: `SELECT Fecha,Cantidad,EMP1,EMP2,EMP4 FROM #Temp`, excluimos con éxito la columna `EMP3`. Ahora solo queda ejecutarla:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

La salida, entiendo es lo que esperas:

```
+----------------------+----------+-------+------+------+
| Fecha                | Cantidad | EMP1  | EMP2 | EMP4 |
+----------------------+----------+-------+------+------+
| 2017-10-24T00:00:00Z | 1        | 0     | 5.96 | 0    |
+----------------------+----------+-------+------+------+
| 2017-10-24T00:00:00Z | 4        | 66.71 | 0    | 0    |
+----------------------+----------+-------+------+------+
| 2017-10-24T00:00:00Z | 8        | 0     | 0    | 4.05 |
+----------------------+----------+-------+------+------+
```

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes. Me ayudo mucho tu respuesta, pero si no te molesta te hago una consulta extra. ¿Existe alguna forma de renovar la información de la tabla temporal? o, ¿limpiar la tabla para volver a cargarla de nueva información para cada consulta nueva?

Comment: La única forma de renovar los datos de la tabla temporal es volver a crearla e insertar los datos de la consulta. Lo bueno de la temporales con un solo `#` en el nombre es que solo "viven" para la conexión que las ha creado, luego de cerrar la conexión, dejan de existir y hay que volverla a "renovar" repitiendo el proceso inicial. Saludos.

Comment: Me anduvo perfecto, muchísimas gracias!!!. Saludos!